# x-y node positioning relative to two different anchor points

Tags: positioning, nodes

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert={size=640}]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  block/.style={draw,rectangle,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm},
  sum/.style={draw,circle,minimum width=0.2cm,minimum height=0.2cm}
]
  \node[block] (g) {$G$};
  \node[sum,above=0.25cm of g.center,right=0.5cm of g] (sum1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

But the `above=0.25cm of g.center` command is ignored at all. How can I achieve this relative positioning of the y-coordinate from a different anchor point?

Comment: you've got *2* positioning commands: `above=0.25cm of g.center,right=0.5cm of g`, so the first is ignored...?

Comment: seems like, but why?

Comment: Try `above right=0.25cm and 0.5cm of g`, mutatis mutandis.

Comment: The point is that I want to use different anchor points for my x and y coordinate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options. The differences in output are because the `right=of` and `above right=of` changes the anchor of the node. `above` sets `anchor=south`, while `above right` sets `anchor=south west`. Indeed you'll see that the bottom of the blue circle and the `south west` point on the black circle is located in the center of the two other circles. By adding `anchor=center` *after* the positioning key all circles end up in the same place.

(As the `east` and `center` anchor has the same y-coordinate, this works. if the node was rotated it wouldn't work.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  block/.style={draw,rectangle,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm},
  sum/.style={draw,circle,minimum width=0.2cm,minimum height=0.2cm},
]
  \node[block] (g) {$G$};
  \node[sum,above right=0.25cm and 0.5cm of g.east] (sum1) {};
  \node[blue,dashed,sum,above=0.25cm of g.east,xshift=0.5cm] (sum1) {};
  \node[red,sum] at ([shift={(0.5cm,0.25cm)}]g.east) {};
  \path (g.east) ++(0.5cm,0.25cm) node[yellow,dashed,sum] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But I want to position the `sum1` node 0.25m above the center of `g` and 0.5cm right from the right edge of `g`.

Comment: @Reza Oops, sorry, didn't pay enough attention to your code. Replace `center` with `east` in my code and you should get that, will edit later.

Comment: The system is not very intuitive, but at least a hack is possible