# picture using LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I try to draw the following picture using LaTeX.
[image]

Comment: Could you post the  code you've already written, trying to achieve this as a minimal working example starting with `\documentclass`?

Comment: Adding to what @Rico said, you didn't provide enough context: Are the black dots and the omega supposed to be placed randomly? What about the `|` and the labels along the ellipse? Please elaborate.

Comment: making a statement, putting in a screenshot, and tagging it `tikz` doesn't make it a 'question'. See if you can follow the template given here, for example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286465/x-y-node-positioning-relative-to-two-different-anchor-points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the start of a TikZ solution.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, multi, tikz]{standalone}
```

We load a library to help with the markings on the outside edges, both the labels and the little lines along the ellipse.

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
```

Start the picture.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
```

We start by drawing the ellipse and filling it. After the ellipse is drawn and filled, we decorate it using two kinds of marks. The first uses a straight arrow tip as a mark for the three small lines. The second creates a node a little ways from the path containing a label. The crucial thing here is that the marks must be given in sequential order, so we need to alternate the two kinds of marks: node, arrow, node, arrow, node, arrow. The path starts from 0 degrees. `pos` indicates the position on the path as a fraction between `0` (start) and `1` (end).

```
  \draw [draw=blue!75!black, fill=blue!50!cyan!15, postaction={decorate, decoration={markings, mark=at position .2 with { \node [above right] {$r_m$}; }, mark=at position .33 with { \arrow{|} }, mark=at position .6 with { \node [below left] {$r_2$}; }, mark=at position .8 with { \arrow{|} }, mark=at position .9 with { \node [below right] {$r_1$}; }, mark=at position 1 with { \arrow{|} } } }] (0,0) circle (7 and 5);
```

To help place things in the ellipse, we add a grid. Comment this out when everything is in final position.

```
  \draw (-7,-5) grid [help lines] (7,5);
```

Now we use a loop to draw the black circles with labels beneath them. All but one of these labels are empty, but the non-empty one gets some text.

```
  \foreach \i/\j in {(3,2)/{Wells/Sinks},(-2,3)/,(4,-1)/,(-1,-1)/,(-5,-2)/} \draw [fill] \i circle (5pt) node [below, yshift=-5pt, font=\itshape\bfseries, anchor=north] {\j};
```

Finally, we add the Omega.

```
  \node at (0,-3.5) {$\Omega$};
```

Close the environment to finish.

```
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: picture with grid for placement]

Commenting out the grid, we get the following result:

[image: picture less grid]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, multi, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [draw=blue!75!black, fill=blue!50!cyan!15, postaction={decorate, decoration={markings, mark=at position .2 with { \node [above right] {$r_m$}; }, mark=at position .33 with { \arrow{|} }, mark=at position .6 with { \node [below left] {$r_2$}; }, mark=at position .8 with { \arrow{|} }, mark=at position .9 with { \node [below right] {$r_1$}; }, mark=at position 1 with { \arrow{|} } } }] (0,0) circle (7 and 5);
  \draw (-7,-5) grid [help lines] (7,5);
  \foreach \i/\j in {(3,2)/{Wells/Sinks},(-2,3)/,(4,-1)/,(-1,-1)/,(-5,-2)/} \draw [fill] \i circle (5pt) node [below, yshift=-5pt, font=\itshape\bfseries, anchor=north] {\j};
  \node at (0,-3.5) {$\Omega$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Obviously, we can also modify the appearance if we wish. For example, we might try using

```
font=\large
```

for the nodes around the ellipse and for the Omega.

Or perhaps a thicker line for the ellipse and a slightly different fill:

```
thick, inner color=blue!50!cyan!15, outer color=blue!50!cyan!35
```

or, even, a variation on the fill for the circles

```
inner color=black!70, outer color=black
```

to give us something more like this:

[image: modified look]

Comment: GREAT answer! We should link to this as a tutorial in the future :)

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the OP is struggling to get off the mark with a MWE in TikZ, here is something that might help someone to get going using `lualatex` and `luamplib`.  The drawing language is Metapost, which you can read about [here](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html).  You need to compile the document with `lualatex` and you need to have installed the TeX Gyre Termes fonts, including the mathematical extensions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\begin{document}
However, a service-oriented paradigm is further compounded when taking into account
the evolution of specifications over a given time period.  
\[
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
% make an ellipse
path e; e = fullcircle xscaled 377 yscaled 233;
fill e withcolor .9[green,white];
draw e withcolor .67 blue;
% draw a dot
fill fullcircle scaled 5 shifted (33,21);
% make some labels
label(btex My text etex, (-42,16));
label(btex $Ω$ etex, (42,-16));
% make a label part of the way round "e"
label.urt(btex $\Gamma_1$ etex, point 0.7 of e);
% draw a bar slightly further round "e"
draw (down--up) scaled 4 
                rotated angle direction 1.414 of e 
                shifted point 1.414 of e;
endfig; 
\end{mplibcode} 
\]
Conversely, any associated supporting element recognizes
other systems' importance and the necessity for possible bidirectional logical
relationship approaches. Does this give you enough ideas to get on with? 
\end{document}
```

Comment: As a side question, why including the MetaPost code into a `\[…\]` environment ?

Comment: @FranckPastor Hi fpast, nice to see you here again.  The `\[ ... \]`  was just to put it into a nice display environment with good spacing top and bottom.  You don't *have* to have maths in a math display!  Of course, you might prefer to wrap it in a `figure` environment.